# Convert geometry to feature with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, expression

With QGIS expressions, if I have a feature, I can get the corresponding geometry with `geometry (feature)`. How is it possible the other way round: if I have a geometry to get the feature (or feature id) of this geometry? Unfortunately, an expression like `feature (geometry)` does not exist. This could be useful to access attributes of this geometry.

If a feature consists of three parts: 1) feature-id, 2) attributes and 3) geometry, than you have expressions to get the corresponding feature for the first two of these three inputs: 1) `get_feature_by_id(layer,feature_id)`
, 2) `get_feature(layer,attribute,value)`. There is missing something like `get_feature_by_geometry (geometry)`.

---

Just to illustrate a use case (the question is **not** about this example: it should just help to understand what this could be used for). I have a point- and a line layer, both in red on the screenshot. To each point, I want to assign the id (or any other attribute)  of the nearest line.

I can easily get the **geometry** of the nearest line: the black dotted copy of the original red line, created with geometry generator on the point layer: `array_first ( overlay_nearest ( 'line', $geometry ) )`. To access the **attributes** of the line, there is the function `attribute ( feature , attribute_name )` . But I first should be able to get the feature-id of the geometry to be able to paste it as first arguement.

QGIS does not accept to input a geometry for the `feature` part of the expression, I get an `Evaluation error: Cannot convert to feature`.

[image]

Comment: Could you expound your `a geometry to get the feature` part? -since in my understanding `feature = geometry + attributes`. If you mean to get the attributes of a particular feature, there are `attribute()` and `attributes()`. E.g to get "fid": `attribute($currentfeature, 'fid')`, or  `attributes($currentfeature)['fid']` if you prefer filtering. Sorry if I misread the question.

Comment: @Kazuhito: I updated the question to make clearer under what circumstances in a more complex expression, you access a geometry - not the one of the current feature - and you want to get the associated feature id to access the attributes.

Comment: `$currentfeature` was just meant for a concise example, but I see your point now; we were talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the feature-id by using `$id` instead of `$geometry` and then use `get_feature_by_id()` to turn this feature-id integer value into an actual feature of a layer. This can then be used to get the `attribute()` or `attributes()`. As a whole:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id('line',array_first(overlay_nearest('line',$id))),'fieldname')
```

You can also skip the `get_feature_by_id()` part by using `$currentfeature` instead of `$id`:

```
attribute(array_first(overlay_nearest('line',$currentfeature)),'fieldname')
```